# Nginx / PHP-FPM hanging connections

Tags: nginx, centos6, php-fpm

I noticed that my server this morning was not responding.   received nginx error page after waiting some time for the page to load. I decided to restart php-fpm because I figured there was an issue serving the php pages. After doing this the website worked per usual.

I'm wondering what could cause this type of behavior?

I checked the error logs for PHP-FPM and there was nothing aside from this.

```
NOTICE: [pool www] child 25155 exited with code 0 after 1028.418645 seconds from start
```

And my PHP-FPM config settings look like

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 200
pm.start_servers = 16
pm.min_spare_servers = 16
pm.max_spare_servers = 32
pm.max_requests = 500
```

My server is a X3440 with 16GB of ram running Centos 6. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Kindly** take a look over this directory in first act for find out more logs :

```
/var/logs/
/var/log/
```

Try with restart in gracefully way (WebServer), try with stop and start back-end server engines, check the disk space then check ram and cpu usage .

**Usefull commands :**

```
free -m
df -h
uptime
```

**either** if still problem exists **inform me** here will **help you** out with future suggestions as well .

PS: You can share logs here , i'll take a look over them ...

Have Great Day Future ***Friend*** ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I have set-up server monitoring so next time this happens I can send you more details. The there's a few TB's of free disk space so this wasn't the cause. I"ll update you here if it happens again.

Comment: You are welcome , i am happy it's helped you out BTW , still you can send them here by checking the /var/log as i have described and evidenced above . feel free for provide future updates ...
Thank you, and have a lovely rest of your day as well.
Nathan.

Comment: Vote UP if you don't mind .!